# Why can't method of a class reference on Interface type

Tags: java, interface

Why we cannot call class method on Interface type which implements that interface..? What's a problem ?

```
Interface {
    void Iaminterfacemethod();
}

Class implements Interface {

    public void Iaminterfacemethod(){
        System.out.println("I'm class implements Interface");
    } 

    void classmethod() {
        System.out.println("I'm class Method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface O = new Class();
        O.classmethod(); --------->Why Not ?
    }
 }
```

If Interface type can reference to class object, than why can't he access class methods ? Because at the end, that call is going to be worked for class's object only..No..?

Comment: Objects are created at runtime, and so the compiler has no idea what type of object is being stored in that reference variable. And so, to keep type safety, one can only invoke methods declared in that class/interface. If you want to invoke a method in `Class`, you would need an explicit cast to `Class`.

Comment: The compiler forgets that the instance is a `Class` as soon as you assign it to an `Interface` variable. This is basic OOP.

Comment: If compiler knows that Interface type can refer to class's object , than what he is waiting for ? He can allow them easily to class methods as well ..No ?

Comment: It can refer to any other type as well. The compiler doesn't know unless you cast it or assign it that specific type.

Comment: @shmosel, "doesn't know unless you cast it or assign it that specific type" Can you share any example how this can be achieved like you said ? Except from class types..! :)

Comment: `((Class)O).classmethod();`

Comment: What is the manning of your title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things happens when you write your code and compile and run.

1. At compile-time compiler checks whether you have correct syntax and method/variable accessibility check.
2. Now, at run-time object would be created and would perform casting and/or boxing(wherever required).

When you write

```
<Interface> O = new <Class>();
O.classmethod();  <-- will be checked at compile time
```

So, basically compiler will check the reference whether `classmethod` exist for `O`, which is your `<Interface>`.

Now, assuming `<Interface>` has been implemented by multiple classes and `classmethod` method was overriden with different behaviors. Then, depending on object of `<Class>` (which implements `<Interface>`), the method would be dynamically bind at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Class O = new Class(); or `((Class)O).classmethod(); If you are using Interface O = new Class();`
```

You can access all the methods.

```
     Interface O = new Class();
```

this is called Dynamic Dispatch. By this you can only access those methods which are in the Interface. Not the other methods which exclusive property of the Class that implements the methods of the Interface.

In your example your Interface has method : `void Iaminterfacemethod();` The class that implements it has another method which is not in the interface i.e. `void classmethod()` by `Interface O = new Class();` `O.Iaminterfacemethod();` is possible but `O.classmethod();` is not. For that you need `Class O = new Class();` now both `O.classmethod();` and `O.Iaminterfacemethod();`  is possible.

Comment: That's not my question.  Please check once again

Answer (score 0):

It is how inheritance works.

```
Interface O = new Class();
```

Here `O` is reference of Interface hence `O` knows only about the method which are defined in Interface.

You can only refer the method which a reference knows about.

Answer (score 0):

Methods declared in your sub-class or implementing class are not part of your super class/interface, thus you cannot invoke those methods which are declared in sub-class with super class/interface reference type. The compiler checks if the reference variable `o` has a method `classmethod()` or not, it doesn't.